# How i can split two users in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I already tried many ways, but not how I can not do the routes and redirect correctly. I want that, if the administrator comes in, they do a re-direct to the dashboard, and if this is just a user, then to home. I ran out of ideas on how to do this. Help me please

role_user_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('role_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
        });
    }
```

roles_table
1. Admin
2. Register user

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }
```

users table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->tinyInteger('role_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });
```

Middleware

```
 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Closure;

  class CheckIfAdmin{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $user = $request->user();

    if (!isset($user)) {
        return redirect('admin/login');
    }

    if (!$user->isAdmin()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

}

Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin::class,
    ];
```

Role.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Role;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return (boolean)$this->roles->where('name', 'admin')->count();
    }
}
```

web.php

```
      Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'namespace'=>'Admin', 'middleware'=> 
   ['auth']], function(){

      Route::resource('/category', 'CategoryController', ['as'=>'admin']);
      Route::resource('/article', 'ArticleController', ['as'=>'admin']);
      Route::group(['prefix' => 'user_managment', 'namespace' => 
   'UserManagment'], function() {
      Route::resource('/user', 'UserController', ['as' => 
    'admin.user_managment']);
      });
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard')- 
   >name('admin.index');
    });
    });
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('blog.home');
    });

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Now he goes to the admin if the admin is registered in the url admin line, if a simple user does it, he won’t miss it, but I need him to automatically throw on the dashboard. dashboard is located in the admin folder

Comment: I don't see any use of the `admin` middleware in your routes or controllers. Where is it being used?

Comment: why does users have a role_id field if you are using the pivot, why does role to user relationship not use the pivot?

Comment: @NMahurin So I don’t know how to do a check and log into the admin correctly. I need everything to show in the admin, and for a simple user only home

Answer (score 0):

Since you have most of the code already written this should work:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'namespace'=>'Admin', 'middleware'=>['admin']], function(){
  Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@dashboard')->name('admin.index');
  Route::resource('/category', 'CategoryController', ['as'=>'admin']);
  Route::resource('/article', 'ArticleController', ['as'=>'admin']);
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'user_managment', 'namespace' => 'UserManagment'], function() {
  Route::resource('/user', 'UserController', ['as' => 'admin.user_managment']);
  });
});


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('blog.home');
}); // Not sure if you want this behind the middleware or not

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

And I would change this line in your middleware:

```
if (!$user->isAdmin()) {
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

So that the non-admin uses are redirect to `/home` per your comment. There's no need to use `Auth` and `admin` middleware here since the `admin` one will handle non admin users. It should allow all admins to reach the group wrapped inside of the `admin` middleware and redirect non admins to the `/home` route. Let me know if this is what you were looking for or if I can refine this for you.

For the redirect issue:

check out: https://codeburst.io/learn-how-to-redirect-authenticated-users-to-corresponding-path-in-laravel-dd613e2f9e3 You can change `protected $redirectTo = 'admin';` to a function: `public function redirectTo(){}`. It'll end up like:

```
public function redirectTo(){

    // User role
    $role = Auth::user()->role->pluck('name')->toArray(); 

    if(in_array('admin', $role)){
        return '/admin/login';
    }else{
        return '/home';
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question, please see. With your method, when I exit the panel, the page is not immediately found. In mine, which I added, everything is fine, but it needs to be thrown right away to the dashboard. Blade.php    dashboard is located in the admin folder

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @NikitaKurilovic When you exit the panel what page isn't found? Can you show your auth controller?

Comment: Using your code, clicking on the user exit, I get thrown Sorry this page not found

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic The logout method is not behind any middleware. I'm guessing your logout method points back to `'/'` which is what the comment was for. Just remove the `->middleware('admin')` part of the `Route::get('/', function()....` part. See the edit.

Comment: It worked. Now the last one. if admin then dashboard if simple user then home. I put COntroller in the Login ``` protected $redirectTo = 'admin';``` , but this is for everyone, but I need only for the admin

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic You can change the redirect to a function. See edit.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

Comment: @NikitaKurilovic it was missing an ending parenthesis in the `if` statement. Are you using an IDE? Normally those minor things get caught pretty easy.

Comment: This function is not work form me(((( p.s. i use sublime text 3 because at home my computer is very slow

Comment: Did you remove `protected $redirectTo = 'admin';` from your controller?

Comment: Yes , he swears at  this `  $role = Auth::user()->role->pluck('name')->toArray();  `